# Will dual booting windows 8.1 with Ubuntu affect the future Windows 10 upgrade?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-8

I currently have Windows 8.1 installed on my Lenovo Flex 2 15 laptop. It comes with Windows 8.1 pre-installed. I want to dual boot my laptop with Ubuntu 14.04, however, I am concerned that it may affect the ability for me to easily upgrade to Windows 10 when it comes out?

Plus, as I have the Lenovo Flex, it can flip around into tent mode. Would it be possible on Ubuntu for it to be able to detect it and rotate the display to match it?

PS. How would I easily be able to remove Ubuntu completely if it clashes with Windows?
Thanks

Comment: Your question about the tent mode/display orientation should probably be posted as another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a reason why you should be concerned. As long as you have enough free disk space on the Windows partition to do the upgrade there should be no further issues. I did an upgrade from Windows 8 to 8.1, where disk space was the only issue I had.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the upgrade to Windows 10 is a new installation, but where all of your data is kept. A new bootloader will definitely be installed, breaking GRUB.

Comment: By breaking Grub, that is fine by me as I know how to fix it. I don't however know if it would stop me from upgrading swiftly to windows 10

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't, Windows 10 will be released via Windows Update, and it's highly unlikely. I'm using the Insider Preview of Windows 10, and it hasn't done anything to Ubuntu, but if you're unsure, wait until around June, when it will be released to Windows Update. If it did break, you could always use the fix install option when you use the Live CD.